# How to avoid timer speeding up when called more than once in C#

Tags: c#, .net

When this function is called twice to restart the timer, the timer speeds up and goes twice as fast when called twice. How to avoid this?

```
public void SetTimer(PlanetarySystem nPlanetsAndSun, int duration, int simulationTimeInterval)
{
    this.simulationTimeInterval = simulationTimeInterval; //milliseconds (dt provided by the user)

    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(simulationTimeInterval); //Create a timer
    timer.Elapsed += UpdatePlanetsAndSimulationTime; //Sets which method to call when timer elapses
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();

    this.nPlanetsAndSun = nPlanetsAndSun;
    this.duration = duration; //milliseconds
}
```

'''

Comment: Q: Have you confirmed that "simulationTimeInterval" is always the same value?  Q: Exactly why are you saying "the the timer speeds up and goes twice as fast"?  I'm sure it "isn't behaving like you expect" ... but I think you might be jumping to the wrong conclusions.  Please provide a bit more information...

Comment: Are you sure you're not just adding multiple timers and the 'speedup' is each timer firing?

Comment: Calling this function twice will not “restart the timer”, it will create a second timer. Now you have two timers both calling `UpdatePlanetsAndSimulationTime`.

Comment: Suggested reading: **[new operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)**

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
if (timer == null) {
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(simulationTimeInterval); //Create a timer
    timer.Elapsed += UpdatePlanetsAndSimulationTime; //Sets which method to call when timer elapses
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();
}
```

If you ever stop / dispose your timer, make sure to also set it to null

```
timer?.Dispose();
timer = null;
```

You could also dispose the old timer at the start of `SetTimer`

System.Timers.Timer (or their callback Handle) will be automatically added to some global static collection when you create them so don't try to override a timer. It won't stop the old one...

Comment: Perhaps `if (timer == null) {  timer?.Dispose(); timer = null; }` and instantiate the timer again with new settings.